# Half H-Bridge Control

Tags: mosfet, resistors, dc-motor, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I need to control a Half H-Bridge circuit to move a DC motor on both clkwise and ctrclkwise directions. I've tested the following circuit:

[image]

It worked as it was supposed to: when the digital input signal (OUT_COM (L)) is LOW, Q5 and M5 are off but M6 is on, so there is GND in the pin OUT_COM (H), which is connected to one of the motor's pin; when the input is HIGH, Q5 and M5 are on while M6 is off, so there is VCC in the output. It works fine when the input is HIGH and the ID current in M5 is just a bit bigger then the current that the motor drains (around 100mA). The problem happens when the input is LOW, because while the M6 ID current is normal (100mA), the ID current in M5 (that was suppost to be 0 at this moment) goes pretty high to around 400mA. I think this is happenning because M5 might not be fully off when the input is LOW because R20 is to big (10k), although I'm not sure if thats the reason because the gate current should be tiny, causing a low voltage drop in the resistor.

Does someone know if R20 is the problem or if there is any other issue in the circuit?

**UPDATE**

R20 was the problem. Because of the current drained by the mosfet's gates, the voltage drop in R20 is to high for deactivating M5 when the input is off, so it stays on and the source is shorted.

Comment: Why not use a full H-bridge?

Comment: Well I'm using two of this so it is a full H-bridge. I just isolated the circuit in this case because of the overcurrent issue.

Comment: "the ID current in M5 (that was suppost to be 0 at this moment) goes pretty high to around 400mA." - what is the voltage across R20 when this happens?